# Why has the Search box reappeared in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10 after September 12 update?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer now looks like this:

[image]

Is anybody else seeing this and how do I get the previous layout back?

Comment: @Ramhound I was hoping there may have been an option somewhere that I hadn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was part of a security update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4038782/windows-10-update-kb4038782.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that one. Is there anything published as to why they have done this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is anybody else seeing this

This change was made to all versions of IE provided you are running

> - Windows 7
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows 10
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
> - Windows Server 2012 R2
> - Windows Server 2016

Here is the list of the patches that introduce this specific change to IE 11

> - KB4038777 — Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Monthly Rollup
> - KB4038792 — Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 Monthly Rollup
> - KB4038788 - Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 Version 1703
> - KB4038782 - Windows 10 Version 1607
> - KB4038783 - Windows 10 Version 1511
> - KB4038781 - Windows 10 (initial version released July 2015)

Sources:

- [Microsoft Security Updates September 2017 release](https://technewsblogs.com/news/microsoft-security-updates-september-2017-release/)
- [Windows 10 Cumulative Updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4038788/windows-10-update-kb4038788)

> How do I get the previous layout back?

In the case of Windows 7 and Windows 8 you would have to remove KB4038777 or KB4038792 (depending on which OS you were using) and instead install the Security-only cumulative update until the end of time.  This is of course because next month's Monthly Rollup patches would include September patches.

> - Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 - KB4038779 - September 12, 2017 (Security-only update)
> - Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 - KB4038793 - September 12, 2017 (Security-only update)

Since you are running Windows 10 you could uninstall the appropriate September patch and defer the installation of the patch until next month.  Since you can only defer these type of updates for I believe its 30 days, you eventually, would have to install the update.  Based on the fact, the change has happen across the board to IE 11, it does not appear you can revert the